# Insertar un documento en HCP con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

Hola espero esten bien,

tengo problemas para subir un documento a HCP (Hitachi)

este es el código que estoy ocupando

```
import http.client
projectName = "Prueba"
hcpConn = ".prueba.local.mex"
headers = {'Authorization': 'HCP ZONud4M=:85e704e0f59a51b987f06485b5f90948'}
h = http.client.HTTPConnection(projectName + hcpConn)
_pt = "C:\Python.pdf"
h.request('PUT', "/rest" + _pt, headers=headers)
```

al momento de ejecutar lo me aparece el siguiente error

> File
>   "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py",
>   line 743, in getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

espero me puedan ayudar. 
saludos!

Comment: Pareciera que no puede resolver "Prueba.prueba.local.mex" como nombre del servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Como dice el comentario de @patricio-moracho te estás conectando
   a un host que no existe. Verifica tus propiedades de red y la
   conectividad (trata de hacerle `ping` por ejemplo)
2. Si estás haciendo pruebas en tu máquina local edita el archivo `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host` y añade la línea.

   127.0.0.1       prueba.prueba.local.mex

o como se llame tu server.

Comment: Si tenian razón tenia mal configurado mi dominio.